# ¿Qué son las dependencias en Laravel y por qué se necesitan?

Tags: laravel

Al hacer deploy de Laravel si migro la base de datos, no necesito el Composer para hacer migraciones y si no hago cambios cuando mi proyecto está en el server tampoco lo voy a necesitar para crear cotrollers, etc... Pero aún así se necesita instalación del Composer para "crear las dependencias". No sé ni qué son ni cómo funcionan ni porqué se necesitan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) es un administrador de paquetes. La idea principal es usar programas que ya funcionan y nos evita volver a escribir el codigo. entonces al desarrollar usamos estos paquetes. lo mismo pasa con el desarrollo de laravel y el desarrollo de las dependencias que usa laravel. Ahora bien, composer hace que todo eso funcione en conjunto. **¿Y cómo lo hace?**

supongamos que tenemos en nuestro composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    }
```

eso significa que en la carpeta **vendor** en nuestro proyecto hay una carpeta **laravel/framework**, y dentro de esta carpeta hay un archivo **composer.json** en la que estan las dependencias de laravel.

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "classpreloader/classpreloader": "~3.0",
        "doctrine/inflector": "~1.0",
        "jeremeamia/superclosure": "~2.2",
        "league/flysystem": "~1.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "~1.11",
        "mtdowling/cron-expression": "~1.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "~1.20",
        "paragonie/random_compat": "~1.4",
        "psy/psysh": "0.7.*",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~5.1",
        "symfony/console": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/debug": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/finder": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "~1.0",
        "symfony/process": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/routing": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/translation": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2"
    },
```

De pronto encontramos todas esas dependencias que son de laravel estan en nuestra carpeta **vendor**. y asi podemos darnos una idea de como se organiza composer.

**¿Como usamos esos programas?**

Dentro de la carpeta vendor se encuentra el archivo **autoload.php**. este es el que incluimos en nuestro proyecto y es el que nos vincula con todas las dependencias a las cuales podemos acceder a traves de **namespaces**, tambien funciona con nuestras propias clases

Para el uso adecuado de [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) puedes leer la documentacion.
Pero la consigna en general es actualizar el autoload (dump) cuando agreguemos dependencias y actualizar en el servidor.